# Find windows home directory from wsl using Python

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

From the WSL2 perspective, the windows home directory is located at
`/mnt/c/Users/<WINUSERNAME>`.

The WSL2 home directory is
`/home/<LINUXUSERNAME>`.

The following python code finds the linux home directory.

```py
from pathlib import Path
home = str(Path.home())


print(home) ## /home/<LINUXUSERNAME>
```

How can I find the windows home directory from a python script running in WSL2? I can not assume that the windows user name is the same as the linux user name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can rely on WSL2<>Windows interoperability, then you can do a few subprocess iterations to figure out:

1. The WSL path of the `cmd.exe` binary (`wslpath -au 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe'`)
2. Invoke cmd.exe to tell you the %USERPROFILE% directory (`<path-to-cmd> /c 'echo %USERPROFILE%'`)

When WSL2 invokes Windows commands they run as the Windows user who owns the WSL2 instance, even if the WSL user is root.

For completion, you might want to consider the fact that the Windows system drive might not be `C:\`, for which case you'd need to do further iterations to check whether the path `\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` exists in the possible disks (`C:\`, `D:\` etc). You can read `/proc/mounts` to look for the mount points that have `Device` equals to `drvfs` and `FsType` entry equals to `9p`. Those are the Windows drives mounted inside WSL.

```bash
❯ cat /proc/mounts | grep drvfs
drvfs /mnt/c 9p rw,dirsync,noatime,aname=drvfs;path=C:\;uid=1000;gid=1000;symlinkroot=/mnt/,mmap,access=client,msize=262144,trans=virtio 0 0
drvfs /mnt/d 9p rw,dirsync,noatime,aname=drvfs;path=D:\;uid=1000;gid=1000;symlinkroot=/mnt/,mmap,access=client,msize=262144,trans=virtio 0 0
```